# Cross-partition paging in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmosDB collection that is partitioned and where throughput is set to 10,000 RU/s (the problem does **not** occur when throughput is below 6100 RU/s).

Now I issue an arbitrary document query (for example to retrieve all documents in the collection) with a variable `pageSize` and a `continuationToken` (initially set to `null`):

```
var q = DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(CollectionUri,
            new FeedOptions
            {
                MaxItemCount = pageSize,
                EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                RequestContinuation = continuationToken
            });
```

Now if I call

```
  FeedResponse<T> response = await q.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
```

I would expect the `response` to be paged according to the specified `pageSize`. In particular, if `pageSize = -1` or `pageSize = int.MaxValue`, I want only exactly one page with all results to be returned. However, the resulting pages are fragmented along the partitions.

For example, with `pageSize = -1` or `pageSize = int.MaxValue` I would get a page with 18 objects from the first partition, and only when `ExecuteNextAsync` is called a second time, I would get the remaining 35 objects from the other two partitions.

With `pageSize = 17` I would first get a page with 17 objects on the first call of `ExecuteNextAsync`, then a page with 1 object on the next call, and then another page with 17 objects!

But this renders paging (almost) completely useless! Or is there a way to implement paging properly (even when throughput is above 6000 RU/s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Nick Chapsas' information that `ExecuteNextAsync` may return fewer than `MaxItemCount` items even if more are available, I am using the following workaround:

```
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        string continuationToken = null;

        IDocumentQuery<T> docQuery = queryable.AsDocumentQuery();

        // ugly hack to get the feed options using reflection
        FeedOptions feedOptions = docQuery.GetNonPublicProperty<FeedOptions>("feedOptions");

        while (docQuery.HasMoreResults && (pageSize <= 0 || result.Count < pageSize))
        {
            if (feedOptions != null && pageSize > 0)
            {
                feedOptions.MaxItemCount = pageSize - result.Count;
            }

            FeedResponse<T> response = await docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
            result.AddRange(response.ToList());

            continuationToken = response.ResponseContinuation;
        }

        return (result, continuationToken);
```

Getting the private property using reflection is not very nice, but there doesn't seem to be any other way to get hold of the query's `FeedOptions`. In particular, the `FeedOptions` used for calling `DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>` are cloned internally, so it's really a private instance.

Answer (score 0):

`MaxItemCount` represents the maximum data that a single request to a partition will return. It is not guaranteed to always be that and sometimes, it will even be empty.

For that reason, you should leave `MaxItemCount` out of your pagination logic, as it has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve.

Instead what you really want is the following:

Here's an implementation with a `pageSize` & `nextPageToken` combo. The continuation token is in the `FeedOptions` of the `query`;

```
var results = new List<T>();
var nextPageToken = string.Empty;
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    if (results.Count == pageSize)
        break;

    var items = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(cancellationToken);
    nextPageToken = items.ResponseContinuation;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        results.Add(item);

        if (results.Count == pageSize)
            break;
    }
}
return (results, nextPageToken);
```

For this to work on any RU/s, you will need to either wrap your `query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(cancellationToken);` call with a retry wrapper or simply rump up the DocumentClient's retry options.

For further implementation details you can take a look on how [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#pagination) handles pagination and solves this issue and more specifically [here](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/develop/src/Cosmonaut/Extensions/CosmosResultExtensions.cs#L228). (Full disclosure, I am the creator of this library but I don't want to paste the full implementation here)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the semantics of ``MaxItemCount``. But I don't see how the code above would work. Suppose ``pageSize = 10``, and the first call to ``ExecuteNextAsync`` returns 20 items. Then ``results`` would correctly contain only the first 10 items (because of the ``break``), but ``nextPageToken`` would point to items starting from #21. Or am I missing something?

Comment: My workaround right now is similar to your code above, but I first get the private property ``query.feedOptions`` using reflection (yuck!) and decrement ``feedOptions.MaxItemCount`` accordingly in each iteration of the ``while`` loop. That guarantees that ``results`` contains exactly ``pageSize`` items (if possible) and ``nextPageToken`` points to the correct following items.